# How to get a France Connect account for a non-French national living abroad?

Tags: france, poland, retirement

A Polish friend of mine worked for a few years in France and is now back in Poland. He is retired and receives a French pension for the time he worked in France.

It is becoming increasingly difficult to access some services without a France Connect account, notably some functionalities of the retirement system.

The France Connect page provides several ways to enable the account, but each of the requires at some point to have a French document (ID card, passport, resident card, ...). My friend does not have any.

**Is there a way for such non-French nationals (EU nationals if this helps) to get a France Connect account?** I am really surprised that this does not pop up in any Google searches as this must be quite a common situation, and yet access to the services is restricted to them.

Comment: What kind of pension is that? Does your friend pay taxes in France? You already tried the tax office maybe?

Comment: @DavidRecallsMonica: this *Retraite* entry is for specific pensions (and is unavailable anyway)

Comment: @Relaxed: he is not a fiscal resident of France so he does not have an account on impots.gouv.fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their website, [Yris](https://www.yris.eu/fr/) supports “European ID titles” and “most passports”. It is listed on the [France Connect website](https://franceconnect.gouv.fr/franceconnect) as an identity provider. A mobile phone is also required and from the language on the website, there might be restrictions on which phones and phone numbers are eligible.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It indeed looks like it accepts non-French documents. I just created my account (with a French document) and I will see him in August to try with his documents. I will be back to confirm whether or not it worked. Thanks again, this is a lifesaver.